# How to display an image inside bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display an image in tooltip when a visiter clicks on the "welcome" link in homepage of my website.

Here is my code so far :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"title='<img src='hello.png'>">Welcome</a>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();});
</script>
```

But it failed to display the image, it displays the html of  image instead. Also I want to change the color of tooltip to Gray .

Is this possible?
Please help.

Comment: Not enough for an answer. I would suggest placing the image element _between_ the anchor tags, and directly before the word Welcome

Comment: Also, I suggest visiting the bootstrap website and reviewing the customize tab. It tells you how to change the color variables of each "mixin" of bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

1) You have mismatched single and double quotes in the title attribute of the `<a>` tag.

2) By default, bootstrap only allows text in the tooltip. You have to set a configuration option to allow HTML.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='hello.png'>">Welcome</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            html: true
        });
    });
</script>
```